# "tabula could not be resolved" and "tabulate could not be resolved from source"

Tags: python, import, python-import, tabula-py

I am trying to extract a table from a PDF, so I tried using tabula-py and tabulate but I keep getting this problem:
""tabula could not be resolved" and "tabulate could not be resolved from source""

The code I used is below:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate

#Reads table from pdf file
df = read_pdf("abc.pdf",pages="all")
print(tabulate(df))
```

I checked that I already have installed tabula and tabulate via Pip.